# Azure Service Plans and non-production slots

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I m looking for the best practice when it comes to azure service plans in a microservice architecture. We have a series of microservices where each is completely independent from each other both in terms of capacity, resources, developers and overall architecture. It goes without saying that if one service experiences issues the other ones should not be affected if not interacting with the problematic service. Those services are hosted in Azure

My question is around Service Plans and how those should related to dev / staging environments. Up until now we would create a service plan for our microservice, call it PersonService. So we would create the PersonService service plan and then the default slot would be production (person-service) and then we would have another staging slot (person-service-staging) to cater for staging / testing needs. All of those would be served under the same service plan.

A terrible thought came to me today that if a dev deploys some horrible bug in staging that eats up all the CPU and / or mem then the production slot would starve from those resources and essentially the staging environment would be affecting the response times of production.

Am I right to think this would be the case? How do you guys recommend to set this up to avoid this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, if person-service-staging starts to consume a significant proportion of the underlying server's resources, it will affect person-service.

Avoiding it very much depends on your current set up and what your priorities are. Adding a dev / test / staging service plan is by far the easiest approach. This leaves your production service plan solely for production ready code. With deployment slots there simply to allow for easy switching between versions (and quick rollback if you realise something in production is broken)

The alternative to this is having a service plan that is solely dedicated to staging that you deploy as part of your testing pipeline. The speed with which Azure can stand up a service plan means that you can create and destroy them on the fly. This gives you the benefit of being able to performance test against your staging server, when it is running on an identical plan to your production code.

One of the major benefits of cloud computing is the ability to crate disposable servers. It takes a deliberate thought to shift out of the old philosophy of 'that's our staging server' Even in a CI scenario - unless you're deploying code every 30 mins! - it can be much cleaner to throw some new servers up to test against. Even if you don't have an automated test pipeline, it is only a matter of a couple of Azure Automation scripts connected to a button on a webpage (though it is surprising how quickly those couple of scripts multiply! into something much more elegant / complicated)

Comment: Thanks - But then how do you take advantage of slot switcing to switch your Staging to Prod? Or do you just not bother?

Comment: @Yannis If your production plan has two slots, then you would deploy to the 'production staging' slot, test to be sure it has deployed properly (at this stage you can do purely functional tests - you know it performs ok) and when you're happy with that, switch slots with live. If, once it is live, you realise something isn't working, you've got a quick roll back solution (switching slots back)